# Static Files are not found (404) when Debug is False

Tags: python, django

I want to see how my app works in production and i changed settings in my local machine, so i used below settings in **settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

STATIC_URL = '/assets/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

I used `python manage.py collectstatic` which copied all the files from folder `static` to `assets`

when i set `Debug = True` files served from `assets` with 200, one example `(http://localhost:8000/assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.js)`
but when i set `Debug = False` the static files are not found with 404 error.

Comment: Post the error log

Comment: `[15/Sep/2017 08:21:40] "GET /assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.js HTTP/1.1" 404 99
[15/Sep/2017 08:21:40] "GET /assets/js/tether.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 97
[15/Sep/2017 08:21:40] "GET /assets/js/bootstrap.js HTTP/1.1" 404 96`  just 404 for all my static files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you turn on debug, you server should take care about static files, anyway if you want continue using in debug = True run it in mode insecure like python `manage.py runserver --insecure`

Comment: Can you explain why django server does not serve static files when `Debug = False`

Comment: because Django server is only for development purpose, for that reason we run in mode insecure, also the server like nginx or apache have a folder only for static files

Comment: For example if you have images or media your server provides these images-media and not Django. Read more https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/

Comment: and this is same case for media files (`MEDIA_ROOT`) as well when i set `Debug = False`

Comment: yes, it is, if I helped don't forget vote up and accep it